# Ruby merge time and date to datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I want to compose a `datetime` object from a time (which is constant in the model) and date (which is attribute stored in database). How can I do it?

Something like that:

```
class Product < AR::Base
  MANUFACTURE_TIME = '08:00' # Is there another way to better write just time?

  def manufactured_at # method, which returns
    # => 1 Jan 2012, 08:00, if self.manufacture_date == Date.new(2012, 1, 1)
    # => 5 oct 2012, 08:00, if self.manufacture_date == Date.new(2012, 10, 5)
    # => 23 Sep 2014, 08:00, if self.manufacture_date == Date.new(2014, 9, 23)
  end
end
```

P.S. I don't know how to store the time constant for this case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a new DateTime using `DateTime.new` and passing the single date components such as year and month.

```
class Product < AR::Base
  MANUFACTURE_TIME = '08:00'

  def manufactured_at
    hour, minute = MANUFACTURE_TIME.split(':')
    DateTime.new(manufacture_date.year, manufacture_date.month, manufacture_date.day, hour, minute)
  end
end
```

You can store the time as you want, even in a array if you don't want to decompose it later using `split`.

Comment: So simple :D. Stackoverflow kills my ability to mind myself... Thanks!

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method "div" for "00":String` for minutes. I'll edit the answer